# CloudFront headers in Next.js missing when navigating to page

Tags: next.js, amazon-cloudfront

I'm working on a sizeable Next.js app hosted on AWS using [serverless-nextjs](https://serverless-nextjs.com/). We have set up the `serverless.yml` file such that CloudFront will pass on the various location headers that are available e.g.:

```
...
cloudfront:
  defaults:
    forward:
      headers:
        [
          CloudFront-Viewer-Country,
          CloudFront-Viewer-Country-Name,
          CloudFront-Viewer-Country-Region,
          CloudFront-Viewer-Country-Region-Name,
          CloudFront-Viewer-Latitude,
          CloudFront-Viewer-Longitude
        ]
...
```

In the home map component `pages/map.tsx`, we can retrieve the location headers in `getServerSideProps`:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
  const userLatHeader = context.req.headers['cloudfront-viewer-latitude'];
  const userLngHeader = context.req.headers['cloudfront-viewer-longitude'];
  const userLocation: LatLngLiteral = {
    lat: userLatHeader ? parseFloat(String(userLatHeader)) : DEFAULT_MAP_CENTRE.lat,
    lng: userLngHeader ? parseFloat(String(userLngHeader)) : DEFAULT_MAP_CENTRE.lng,
  };

  return {
    props: {
      userLocation,
    }
  }
}
```

We use the location headers to centre on the user's location when the map loads. We have found that if we visit the map page directly i.e. `address.com/map`, the correct CloudFront header values are found and we can use them to centre and zoom the map to the current location. However, if we navigate from a different page to the map page using a `next/link` component e.g.:

```
index.tsx

<Link href={{ pathname: '/map', query }}>
  <a>Go to map</a>
</Link>
```

The map will load using the defaults for the `userLocation`, because the CloudFront headers are coming through as `undefined` in `getServerSideProps`. What could be causing this? If I retrieve the same headers in `getServerSideProps` in `index.tsx` and log them out, they are the expected location values, but then when navigating to `pages/map.tsx` from there they come through as `undefined`.

Comment: If you go directly to `/map` in your browser, are the headers properly set then?

Comment: Yes they are - it has something to do with navigating from one page to the other with `next/link` or `next/router`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update behaviours in Cloudfront. Edit behavior for `_next/data/*` and add `CloudFront-Viewer-Country` for Headers -> Include the following headers under Cache key and origin requests.

[image]